# how to make grid css layout with 3 items and 2 columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I have three items that I would like to layout in 2 columns.

Item 1 is taller than Item 2 and 3.

Here is my css.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1">hi there</div>
    <div class="item2">hi there</div>
    <div class="item3">hi there</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get it to look like this:
[image]

Here is what I've tried:

try 1:

```
.container {
    display:flex;
}
```

Makes 3 columns, lined up in 1 row.

try 2:

```
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This makes the layout look like this:
[image]

try 3:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-areas: "1 2" "1 3";
}

.item1 {
    grid-area: 1;
}

.item2 {
    grid-area: 2;
}

.item3 {
    grid-area: 1;
}
```

this doesn't seem to work as everything stacks up on itself in a single column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use pure numbers in `grid-template-areas`, try it this way:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "A B"
      "A C";
}

.item1 {
    grid-area: A;
    background: red;
}

.item2 {
    grid-area: B;
    background: green;
}

.item3 {
    grid-area: C;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1">hi there</div>
    <div class="item2">hi there</div>
    <div class="item3">hi there</div>
</div>
```